# Geolocation - how to get city from long and lat

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, geolocation

I am trying to get the `city` out of `Geolocation API`. I have just started some JS and jQuery learning so it might be a basic mistake.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function displayLocation(latitude,longitude){
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

        var method = 'GET';
        var url = 
            'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=' 
            + latitude + ',' + longitude + '&sensor=true';
        var async = true;

        request.open(method, url, async);
        request.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200){
                var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                var address = data.results[0];
                alert(address.city.short_name);
            }
        };
        request.send();
    };

    var successCallback = function(position){
        var x = position.coords.latitude;
        var y = position.coords.longitude;
        displayLocation(x,y);
    };

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successCallback);
});
```

Comment: What does your code actually produce?

Comment: An error in the console of web dev tools: 

TypeError: address.city is undefined

When I change the alert to be: 

alert(address.formatted_address); 

it returns the whole formatted address, but I only need the city name

Comment: highlited the key points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        function displayLocation(latitude,longitude){
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

       var method = 'GET';
       var url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='+latitude+','+longitude+'&sensor=true';
       var async = true;

       request.open(method, url, async);
       request.onreadystatechange = function(){
       if(request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200){
         var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
         alert(request.responseText); // check under which type your city is stored, later comment this line
         var addressComponents = data.results[0].address_components;
         for(i=0;i<addressComponents.length;i++){
            var types = addressComponents[i].types
            //alert(types);
            if(types=="locality,political"){
               alert(addressComponents[i].long_name); // this should be your city, depending on where you are
             }
           }
        //alert(address.city.short_name);
       }
    };
   request.send();
 };

 var successCallback = function(position){
 var x = position.coords.latitude;
 var y = position.coords.longitude;
 displayLocation(x,y);
  };


 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successCallback);

  });
 </script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it firstly displays a list of (probably) every single possible value of the location and after clicking "Ok" it shows the city. Is it because of the for loop?

Comment: Sorry, just read the code more carefully and noticed you pointed at the line that needs to be commented out! It works fine, thanks!